# Android Google Maps grey screen when downloaded from Google Play

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, screen

basically I have made an app on Android Studio and when I run the app on my phone the Google Maps activity runs perfectly. However I have since put the app on Google Play and when people download it, the Google Maps activity only shows a grey screen. Any ideas on why this is? I've done all the SHA1 fingerprint stuff and have an API key, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Comment promoted to answer:*

It's probably because the SHA1 of your release key does not match the SHA1 of your debug key. Add another entry in your API console (under the Google Maps section) with your existing package name and the SHA1 for your release key, and you should be all set.

Comment: This is probably going to sound like a stupid question. But where do I find the debug key and the release key to compare them?

Comment: Your debug key is typically located somewhere in `~/.android` on a Mac (not sure about Windows). Your release key, if using Android Studio, was probably generated for you. You can locate it by checking the Project Structure -> Signing tab, see e.g. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio